# Match documents with fields not containing values in $group

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query

I have a collection that looks like this:

```
{
    id: 1
    user: 1
    gameCategory: aaa/traditional
    gameName: Artifact
},
{
    id: 2
    user: 1
    gameCategory: web3
    gameName: Axie Infinity
},
{
    id: 3
    user: 2
    gameCategory: aaa/traditional
    gameName: League of Legends
},
...
```

A single document indicates a user playing a game. How would I find the group of users who:

- only play "aaa/traditional" games
- only play "web3" games
- play both types of games

My idea is to run the $group stage with user & gameCategory, and use $match or something to filter out users who also play other categories of games

Comment: Do you want the 3 lists in one query?

Comment: If that is possible, yes! If not I can work with 3 separate queries.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**EDIT:** There are many options here. This is a simple one:

1. We use the `$group` to store for each user its `gameCategory`, but also to check if they play on another game, hence fill `other`. This allows us to store on `groupType` only `gameCategory` that is a key to a group
2. If `groupType` contains only one key, this is the group key, otherwise it is 'both'
3. This is true only if `other` key is empty.
4. `$group` by `groupType` and aggregate the users of the group

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$user",
      other: {
        $addToSet: {
          $cond: [
            {$and: [{$ne: ["$gameCategory", "web3"]},
                    {$ne: ["$gameCategory", "aaa/traditional"]}]
            }, "true", "$$REMOVE"]
        }
      },
      groupType: {
        $addToSet: {
          $cond: [
            {$or: [{$eq: ["$gameCategory", "web3"]},
                   {$eq: ["$gameCategory", "aaa/traditional"]}]
            }, "$gameCategory", "$$REMOVE"]
         }
      }
    }
  },
  {
    $project: {
      other: {$size: "$other"},
      groupType: {
        $cond: [{$eq: [{$size: "$groupType"}, 1]}, {$arrayElemAt: ["$groupType", 0]},
          "both"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  {$project: {groupType: {$cond: [{$eq: ["$other", 1]}, "other",  "$groupType"]}}},
  {$group: { _id: "$groupType",  users: {$push: "$_id"}}}
])
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ga4cqFEsEWl)

Comment: Extremely cool idea, and I feel that you may be close. But your query breaks when the same user has played multiple different games of the same category. 

I edited the playground a little you can see what happens when I let 1 user play 2 aaa/traditional games and a web3 game

https://mongoplayground.net/p/EJ8Qb0CSsqJ

Comment: I'm trying to do it with a $reduce, $regexMatch on the array with gameCategories

Comment: Fixed that on the first query

Comment: Nice! There are simplifications that can be made, but you definitely helped me out. Thanks!